# How to animate remove action in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout, widget, android-custom-view

I want to create custom container, that can lay children one by one from bottom with offset. Currently I created such container but I have problems with animation, when view is added to container it should slide from bottom, when view is remove it should slide to bottom. With add animation all fine, but with remove I got some issues, views dont want to go in needed position?

This is onLayout() method:

```html
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);

                int offset;
                if (i > (itemCount - VISIBLE_ITEMS)) {
                    offset = (itemCount - i - 1) * this.offset;
                }
                // we adding invisible items
                else {
                    offset = (VISIBLE_ITEMS - 1) * this.offset;
                }

                int bottom = getBottom() - offset;
                int left = getLeft();
                int right = getRight();
                int top = bottom - child.getMeasuredHeight();

                child.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

This is method for adding new view:

```html
public void animateAdd(final View view){
        addView(view);
        final ViewTreeObserver observer = getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                AnimatorSet animator = new AnimatorSet();
                for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = getChildAt(i);
                    int startY = i == getChildCount() - 1 ? child.getHeight() : offset;
                    if (isNeedToAnimate(i)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreDraw: startY = " + startY);
                    animator.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(child, TRANSLATION_Y, startY, 0));
                    animator.playTogether(createColorAnimator(child, i));
                    }
                }
                animator.setDuration(300);
                animator.start();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

This is method for remove action:

```html
public void animateRemove() {
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final View removeView = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        removeViewInLayout(removeView);
        final ViewTreeObserver observer = getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                final AnimatorSet animator = new AnimatorSet();
                for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = getChildAt(i);
                    int endY = i == getChildCount() - 1 ? child.getHeight() : offset;
                    if (isNeedToAnimateRemove(i)) {
                    Animator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(child, TRANSLATION_Y, endY);
                    animator.playTogether(anim);
                    animator.playTogether(createColorAnimator(child, i));
                    }
                }
                animator.setDuration(300);
                animator.start();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```